# Last login command, alias in csh

Tags: linux, alias, csh, last

In the C shell, how can we display the login history of a particular user using an alias in such a way that the user only enters the alias name and the number of lines to be displayed without typing his/her username?

Comment: This sounds like homework... what have you tried on your own?

Comment: alias login 'last -n '

Comment: This would depend on what Unix you are using as the `last` command works slightly differently on many of them. For example, a BusyBox-based system would have a quite limite implementation of `last` while FreeBSD or Ubuntu would have options that would allow you to do exactly waht you are asking for (and would be easy to wrap in a shell function).

Comment: i use c shell its just that the login history of user using the command should be displayed without the user having to mention the username

Comment: this sounds like you want to *modify* what the `last` command does. Is that correct?